# Merge Arrays of Objects, Modifying Some Resulting Entries

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter

I have the following code, which takes 2 arrays of objects in JavaScript and compares them and merges the contents, returning all objects from the 1st array, plus all objects from the 2nd that have an id that's not in the 1st.

But for those items that come from the 2nd array, I want to modify its entry in the new array to only include certain properties (e.g., id & make) and to add a new placeholder property (e.g., type: "car"). I believe this would use the map function, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```js
    var cars1 = [
        {id: 1, make: "Ford",  model: "F150",  year: 2002},
        {id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003},
    ];

    var cars2 = [
        {id: 2, make: "Kia",    model: "Optima",  year: 2001},
        {id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra",  year: 1982},
    ];

    const cars1IDs = new Set(cars1.map(({ id }) => id));
    const combined = [
      ...cars1,
      ...cars2.filter(({ id }) => !cars1IDs.has(id))
              .map(cars2 => cars2.id)
    ];
    combined.sort(({ id: aId }, {id: bId }) => aId - bId);
    console.log(combined);
```

I want the combined array to end up with the following contents:

```
var combined = [
    {id: 1, make: "Ford",   model: "F150",  year: 2002},
    {id: 2, make: "Kia",    type: "car"},
    {id: 3, make: "Chevy",  model: "Tahoe", year: 2003},
    {id: 4, make: "Nissan", type: "car"},
];
```

But instead it ends up as:

```
var combined = [
    {id: 1, make: "Ford",   model: "F150",  year: 2002},
    {id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003},
    2,
    4
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `.map`, you should extract the `id` and `make` properties, and return an object containing just those properties plus a `type` of `car`:

```js
var cars1 = [
    {id: 1, make: "Ford",  model: "F150",  year: 2002},
    {id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003},
];

var cars2 = [
    {id: 2, make: "Kia",    model: "Optima",  year: 2001},
    {id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra",  year: 1982},
];

const cars1IDs = new Set(cars1.map(({ id }) => id));
const combined = [
  ...cars1,
  ...cars2.filter(({ id }) => !cars1IDs.has(id))
          .map(({ id, make }) => ({ id, make, type: 'car' }))
];
combined.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
console.log(combined);
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should change map function
Here is code. Only map function of car2 is change

```
var cars1 = [
        { id: 1, make: "Ford", model: "F150", year: 2002 },
        { id: 3, make: "Chevy", model: "Tahoe", year: 2003 }
      ];

      var cars2 = [
        { id: 2, make: "Kia", model: "Optima", year: 2001 },
        { id: 4, make: "Nissan", model: "Sentra", year: 1982 }
      ];

      const cars1IDs = new Set(cars1.map(({ id }) => id));
      const combined = [
        ...cars1,
        ...cars2
          .filter(({ id }) => !cars1IDs.has(id))
          .map(car2 => {
              //add new prop type to car
              const tempCar2 = Object.assign(car2,{type:"car"});
              //remove year and model
              delete tempCar2.year                    
              delete tempCar2.model
              return tempCar2;
            //Object.assign(car2, { id: car2.id });
          })
      ];
      combined.sort(({ id: aId }, { id: bId }) => aId - bId);
      console.log(combined);
```